# Cable for my oil-pressure sensor?

Tags: mercedes-benz, oil-pressure-sensor

I have a Mercedes B180 (Diesel) that is showing a light on the dashboard: a little engine symbol. I've had a mechanic look at it, and the code said 'oil pressure sensor', so it was changed. The light still comes on and it is the same fault code - the theory is that it is the cable from the sensor that is bad, so perhaps I should try to change that.

However, some cars, I know, have cables that are basically integrated into one, large bundle, in which case you have to replace the whole lot; a Mazda I owned years ago was like that - one of the connectors to the headlight was rusty, and it would cost £300 (+ work, of course) to fix. You can see why I'm hesitating.

So, could anybody give me some idea about whether this is a simple cable or an expensive, integrated thing? If you know a part number too, that would be great, then I could call Mercedes and ask for a price.

Comment: Instead of changing parts (ie: sensor, and now wiring), you should prove the problem is the wiring. Has the mechanic checked the connector to the sensor? Has the mechanic checked to ensure the sensor which was installed is actually good/working? Are you ***sure*** you actually have oil pressure? There's a ton of things which should have been checked well before parts were replaced. It's always good to know what you're working on, because the alternative of "Remove & Replace" gets expensive really fast.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I agree, he should, but ... As for myself, I'm not sure of anything except that it costs me money, and there is a balance to be struck between spending money on checking and spending it on trying to change a thing if it isn't too expensive. If I knew about cars, I wouldn't go to a mechanic as much.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, however, when it comes to cost, when you "R&R" instead of diagnosing, it will *invariably* cost you more money. As it stands, you should ask for them to replace the old part and get your money back.

Comment: Checking that you really have oil pressure is **very** cheap compared to replacing a blown engine.

Comment: @SolarMike Not sure if I understand - you mean whether I actually have oil in the engine? I know that, at least; the car is serviced regularly, and of course I check the dipstick myself.

Comment: I am a strong believer in diagnosing then repairing. But there is a flip side. If there is a known problem or history of a car having oil pressure sending unit s going bad and the part costs around $25, I would make sure the actual oil pressure was good and change the sensor without troubleshooting. Chances are good that it was a quick and inexpensive fix. If not, then my gamble didn't pay off and it will cost me to take the time to diagnose the wiring or instrument panel. Usually in a rare instance as this, you usually come out ahead.

Comment: The #1 priority here is to determine whether or not there is an actual oil pressure issue with your engine.  It shouldn't take more than 1 hour of labor for a competent mechanic to connect an oil pressure gauge to your engine and measure the pressure.

Answer (score 2):

It is highly unlikely you will find any modern car that will have a totally separate cable just for the oil pressure sensor.  The engine will likely have a single harness that has all connections integrated.

That being said, a decent mechanic should be able to diagnose if there is a broken wire or a bad connector.  If it is a bad connector, it shouldn’t be difficult to replace the connector.   If there is a broken wire an additional wire could be added to the harness to substitute for the broken one.

The wire from the oil pressure sensor will undoubtedly go to the engine ECU, so it should be easy enough to check with a multimeter and replace the single wire if necessary.

As others have commented, it is essential that you know that the oil pump is working and supplying the correct oil pressure.  Oil sat in the sump will not lubricate the engine.

The mechanic should be able to screw in a mechanical oil pressure gauge to verify that the oil pump is working correctly.